# 'Point' is ambiguous in Arcobject.net

Tags: .net, arcobjects

```
  Ipoint declared as New Point showing the error .
```

"'Point' is ambiguous,imported from the namespace or types 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry,System.Drawing'"

Comment: In future you have to make this a little clearer

Comment: Please describe your problem next time, not just show a error with no other information.

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the used namespace by writing

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point myPoint = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point();
```

Or try removing unused usings to avoid such ambiguousnesses.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you can choose to either fully qualify one or both of those, or you can use an alias when you import as follows:

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using drw = System.Drawing; // I tend to do this for the one I'll use less.

static void UseThisInAnExample()
{
    // Create a point from arc gis...
    var declared = new Point();
    // Create the normal system drawing one....
    var theOtherOne = new drw.Point(5, 5);
}
```